# reloadSections doesn't work inside an if

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if (_needRefresh)
    { NSLog(@"Type This If You Are IN");
        [self.myTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        _needRefresh = NO;
    }
```

I want to refresh my table only if something is changed. the code `[self.myTableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` works great when I move to the `viewController` but when I put it inside `if` something is going wrong. I can see that the `NSLog` from inside the if is printed so I don't understand what's the difference and why the reloading is not getting executed.

Comment: how many sections do you have?

Comment: just one. The code is identical. One time without an if and one time with an if.

Comment: Do you get any kind of error message?

Comment: no but if i remove `_needRefresh = NO;` from inside the if, well, that fixes it. I don't understand why. The reloading is called before the `_needRefresh = NO;`

Comment: Try moving the code in the viewDidAppear method and see if this changes anything

Comment: There its running the code twice and there's no animation.